# how to compile or rebuild particular theme in magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.0

whenever I **bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy** it will create all theme or compile all theme

but in my case I need to recompile or rebuild my specific theme in that case how to do it in magento2?

Answer (score 4):

**As of 2.1.1 you can now deploy specific themes**

**Deploy specific themes:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend
```

**Exclude themes:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Magento/luma
```

The following command deploys static content for the US English (en_US) language, excludes the Luma theme provided with Magento, and does not minify HTML files.

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to deploy static files in 2.0.* only for your theme. You need to upgrade to 2.1.1 if you want to deploy specific theme only.

From version 2.1.1 there is `--theme` option for `setup:static-content:deploy` command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Vendor/mytheme
```

There is also options for excluding themes or deploy/exclude arias  such as adminhtml or frontend.

[Check official documentation here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Comment: can 2.1.0 deploy specific theme?

Comment: No, it's feature from 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.1.1 you are able to content deploy specific themes and also exclude themes by this commands:

Content Deploy **specific themes** By this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Vendor/firsttheme --theme Vendor/secondtheme
```

Also you can **exclude themes** By this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Vendor/yourtheme
```

If you need deploys static content for **particular language (en_US)**, and exclude other theme, and need **not minify HTML files** then use this command:

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Vendor/yourtheme --no-html-minify
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try delete your theme static content in pub/static/frontend/YOURTHEME, and clear cache - refresh site to view change.

Comment: can we run static-content:deploy for specific theme or not if we run the command it will create all theme i dont want to create all theme again just i need to re deploy only my theme

Answer (score 0):

It seems frontend argument only has info:language:list for list of available locales please refer [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)